# facebook api and images

Tags: php, facebook, html, api

is there a way to pull the images I have on my facebook page or facebook profile and show them on my website, is it possible? is there a link for documentation? I googled it not much luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Facebook Graph API provides you the access to get the JSON data from there server. It's a combination couple of steps likes app creation, login authentication, app access to photo etc.

More read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: duh. Im stupid sometimes. I saw it I thought it was from graphs like drawing pipelines etc... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a project like this the past few days..

Using the Graph API of Facebook and jQuery.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

I used the jQuery Deferred object to execute a function when the FB.api call has been finished and the data has been loaded.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

If you are outputting photos from albums, please note that you can't ask for a specific with and height. The types album, small and thumbnail are allowed to load.